# How to write custom action in install shield?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, custom-action

I have a custom action that runs an executable file(which will be insatlled in the registry) only if that executable is not installed.
I want the executable to install every time when i run the MSI(over write the installed exe in the registry). Could any please provide the custom condition to do the same.

Currently i'm using the condition as: Not installed in the Install exe condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want for 'exe' file to be executed every time, just remove the condition.
If you want your 'exe' to be executed if that 'exe' is not been executed before, you can check the specific registry value and you can set a property accordingly and use that property in the condition.

Please elaborate the question to get the exact answer for your problem.